# Manage and ID 100+ computers remotely

Tags: windows, software-rec, remote-access, remote-control, administration

I recently built 150 new PCs for our office and I'd like to be able to manage them remotely or on-site from a single computer. I've been researching using Remote Administration Tools. But from what I can find they are usually built for malicious use and contain tools/apps that are useless for this sort of application.

Requirements:

- Ability to run a batch script on all computers simultaneously (Eg; start/stop a program on all PCs)
- **A simple way of giving each computer an I.D. preferably done on the "slave" PC. So that when someone has an issue they can say "PC 124 has a problem... As the number would be labeled on that users desk/monitor".**
- LIGHTWEIGHT (all of the PC's are very critical and the program must maintain a low amount of usage when not being actively controlled"
- View a list of running processes
- (optional) View some sort of Device Manager.

All of these PC's are **VERY** important. They all must be running and starting the programs required within a very short amount of time. Our network is extremely robust so i'd rather not have a inefficient program bottle necking it.

TL;DR - Need a lightweight Remote Admin Tool without all of the malicious bull shit tools and some sort of ID solution.

Comment: Depending on need, you should check out [NetBox](https://netbox.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: I think the right place to ask is [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), although the site doesn't seem very active. Note you're still asking for software recommendation (explicitly by TL;DR and the tag).